# Prevent direct access to action form

Tags: php

I have a form.php wich action call sql.php file like:

SQL.PHP

```
if ($_REQUEST['action'] == "add") {
}
if ($_REQUEST['action'] == "edit") {
}
```

I'm like to prevent direct access, because user can call from browser url: http://sql.php?action=add
One way is check if a submit. Seem work well.

```
if( isset($_POST['Submit']) && ($_POST['Submit'] == "Submit") )
{
echo "direct access not allowed";
}
```

There is better alternatives?

Comment: You cannot prevent it

Comment: Easy answer: add tokens to your form.

Comment: Hello Class, How to add a token, have you any reference or example?

Comment: @user2307958 this will give you a start but you might want to modify it to meet your needs [Cross-Site Request Forgeries](http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-request-forgeries)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` array to detect if someone is accessing your page directly by typing in it into the browser, or comming from another one of your pages, by a use of links from a page.

So, basically.

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'about.php'){
//let user do something
}
```

So, the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` global stores information of the pages you visit, and if you place echo that code, in your page, it will tell you from which page your are comming from. meaning, that if you only typed the page and access it, it will give `0/false` value.

So, you can use it to detect if someone is directly typing the page or comming from one of your pages.

---

As others have indicated already, using tokens, and sessions would be a better idea since this method can be manipulated. So, I recommend you google them out

Comment: Referrers can easily be spoofed.

Comment: @j08691 I could recommend him sessions also, but for a newbee this would be a basic/good choise. but, I'll throw in a mention of sessions

Answer (score 0):

It should be `if(!isset($_POST['Submit'])` . Also if you use `method="POST"`, it does not throw your parameters like `?action=add` at the browser. `method="GET"` does it.